# reconnecting to nodejs websocket on failure

Tags: node.js, angular

This is my first practice after reading some tutorials and videos. Basically, I need message to be sent from the server (nodejs) to the client (Angular 6). At first tho, when client app is booted, it sends user id to the server for authentication. The server then will send data based on that user.

Now my problem is on first load and a few calls, the connection does work. But then on refresh or so, the connection drops. My client does console out "retrying" but it never succeeds. It works only if I manually restart the server and reload the client so a new connection could be established.

How can I maintain a fairly stable connection throughout the lifetime of a client? At times the readyState stays at 3 on the server i.e. connecting, which I am confused with because the client does try to reconnect...just fails.

My Server is simple. index.js (Tried to put it up on stackblitz but failed...would appreciate if someone can figure out the dependency file: [nodejs websocket server](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-vpkkzv))

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const pg = require ('pg');

var ws = require('./ws')

var app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('We are running on port 3000!')
})
```

ws.js:

```
 const winston = require('winston');
const logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'error.log'})
    ]
});



var WebSocketServer = require("ws").Server,
  wss = new WebSocketServer({
    port: 40511
  });


let data = {
  'packet': ['amy1', 'amy2', 'amy3']
}
const mx = 2;
const mn = 0;
wss.on("connection", function(ws) {
  ws.on("message", function(user) {
    // client has called now. If the connection
    // fails, the client does try to connection again and again -- no limit but it simply doesn't seem to have effect. When connecting, it simply sends user name
    console.log("received: %s", user);

setInterval(function(){ 
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (mx - mn + 1) + mn);
    if (ws.readyState == ws.OPEN){
      ws.send(data['packet'][random]);
    }
 }, 3000);



  });
});
```

My front end is: service.ts

```
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';
export class WebSocketService {
  socket: WebSocket;

  constructor() { }

  initConnection(): void {

    if(!this.socket){
      this.socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:40511');
      // when connection is open, send user id
      this.socket.onopen = () => this.socket.send(2);
    }

  }

  manageState() : Observable<any>{
    const vm = this;
    return new Observable(observer => {

      this.socket.onerror = (e) => {
        // close it
        this.socket.close();
        observer.next('web socket communication closed due to error')

      };

      this.socket.onclose = (e) => {
        //socket closed for any reason
        setTimeout(function() {
          console.log('try to connect')
          vm.initConnection();
          observer.next('still trying')
        }, 1000);
      }

    });
  }




  onMessage(): Observable<any> {
    // when message arrives:
    return new Observable(observer => {

      this.socket.onmessage = (e) => {
        console.log(e.data);
        observer.next(e.data)
      };



    });
  }

}
```

component.ts:

```
// initialize the connection

this.service.initConnection();

this.service.onMessage().subscribe(
            data => {
                // we have got data
              console.log('data came ', data)
            },
            err => {
                console.log("error websocking service ", err);
            }
        );
        // track state of the communication, letting the service to reconnect if connection is dropped
        this.service.manageState().subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
        });
```